# Show the identity $4\sin^2(z)\cos^2(z)=\sin^2(2z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

For the complex functions $sin(z)$ and $cos(z)$, my professor has written:

$$\sin^2(z)\cos^2(z)=1 \implies 4\sin^2(z)\cos^2(z)=4 \implies \sin^2(2z)=4$$

I am unsure if some other trickery is going on or if this equality is true all the time. It seems to me that it is not.

Comment: Are you okay with$ \sin(2x)=2\sin(x) \cos(x)$?

Comment: This is called double angle formula for sine function.

Comment: I mean for the complex sin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
4\sin^2z\cos^2z
&= 4\left(\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right)^2 \\
&= 4\left(\dfrac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}-2}{-4}\right)\left(\dfrac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}+2}{4}\right) \\
&= \left(\dfrac{(e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz})^2-4}{-4}\right) \\
&= \left(\dfrac{(e^{2iz}-e^{-2iz})^2}{(2i)^2}\right) \\
&= \left(\dfrac{e^{2iz}-e^{-2iz}}{2i}\right)^2 \\
&= \sin^22z
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't it better to prove that $2\sin\, z \cos\, z=\sin\, (2z)$ and then square it so that the proof looks 'neater'?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Anyway I think, I proved what OP wanted.